# Java Text Reading

Tags: java, twitter

I am making a project which reads a text file contains thousands of tweets, reads the file, splits the hastags and make operations on them. I wrote a text file by myself and everything worked fine. I tried to use text file in this website http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cdmurphy/cit595/homework/tweets.txt  and I got a problem. Part of my code is :

```
while (scan.hasNext())
            {
             //Operations
            }
```

When I use the text file on that website, code skips this loop. According to Java, that text file hasn't got next lines. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with that file? Since my project will be graded by using that text file, I have to find the problem.

Comment: Can you show us how you implemented Scanner to read from a file? Also, can you replicate the structure and a sample of that file here, so we don't have to go off-site to see your entire question?

Comment: The link for tweets.txt is dead. Also, you wont get any answers until we can see what code you have so far. Post it up!

Comment: @Jimmy I have solved my problem. I got error because file was too big for Scanner to read. I used BufferedReader to read that file and problem solved. Thank you anyway!